# How to get the Status of a Server if the Website is Down (Timeout)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**How to get the Status of a Server if the Website is Down (Timeout)?**

1. Currently my program identifies the status of the server if the website is up and running.
2. For example if the website is okay = 200.
3. If the wrong page is shown = relevant server status.
4. If the website is down (Timeout), my code dosnt work and therefore no email is sent.

code: 
Get the server status:

```
public class ServerStatus {
    public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        huc.connect();
        return huc.getResponseCode();
    }
}
```

**Email the status of the information gained (Will not work if the server is down / timeout 'My Problem'):**

```
 public void EmailFormatAndDataCapture(ITestResult testResult) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    if (testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE || testResult.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        String tempTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss").format(new Date());
        serverStatusMap.put("\n Time:" + tempTime + " , Test Method: " + testResult.getName() + ", Server Status", ServerStatus.getResponseCode(basePage.getCurrentURL().toString()));
        failedSkippedTests.put("\n Time:" + tempTime, " Class name: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + ", Test Method Name: " + testResult.getName());
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in getResponseCode() docs it throws IOException - if an error occurred connecting to the server.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode()

You should handle this exception using try catch clause. For example:

```
try{
   // here getStatus
} catch (IOException e){
   // handle your timeout scenario
}
```

**Edit:**

Probably Exception will be thrown earlier when you try to establish connection so you must choose where you need to catch the Exception to meet your requirements.

Comment: thanks for you help, how would i return the exception if  my method is of type int and i need it to be of type int inorder to send via email

Comment: You should read about how Exceptions works in Java. It have nothing to do with your return type. Here you can read more about exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: thanks im not sure it would then be possible to return the exception as type int and append to my email with the above code>?

Comment: It's not possible to return Exception as int but it's possible to return int in catch clause. It's up to you how you will implement your catch clause, and on which method you will catch the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

#### CODE

```
public class ServerStatus {
    private static final int INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE = -1;
    private static final int MALFORMED_URL = -999;
    private static final int STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT = -998;
    private static final int UNEXPECTED_IO_EXCEPTION = -997;

    private static Throwable lastException=null;

    private static void setLastException(Throwable t) {
        lastException=t;
    }

    public static String getLastStatusDetails() {
        StringBuilder statusDetails= new StringBuilder();

        if (lastException!=null) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

            lastException.printStackTrace(pw);

            String lastExceptionStackTrace = sw.toString();
            statusDetails.append(lastExceptionStackTrace);
        }

        // You may append other useful information to the details...
        return statusDetails.toString();
    }

    public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) {
        int ret;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
            huc.connect();
            ret= huc.getResponseCode();
        } catch(MalformedURLException mue) {
            setLastException(mue);
            ret=MALFORMED_URL;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
            setLastException(ste);
            ret=STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT;
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            setLastException(ioe);
            ret=UNEXPECTED_IO_EXCEPTION ;
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

#### SAMPLE USAGE

```
 int responseCode = ServerStatus.getResponseCode("http://example.com/service");

 if (responseCode < 0) {
     switch(responseCode) {
         case STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT:
             sendMail("From", "To", "Subject: Server down", "Body: " + ServerStatus.getLastStatusDetails());
         break;

         // Handle other response codes here...

         default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected response code: " + responseCode);
     }
 }
```